# Why unsetting max and min width/height css properties require different values?

Tags: css, specifications

Consider this CSS:

```
min-height: none;
max-width: none;
max-width: auto;
min-height: auto;
```

This yields the following 'Invalid property value' errors.

[image]

Why is it that 'unsetting' `min-[prop]` requires the `auto` value while unsetting `max-[prop]` requires the `none` value?

I'm intrigued by the rationale behind this decision in the spec.

Comment: Ain't web design grand! They do it to keep us on our toes...

Just use `unset`. Works every time.

Comment: @allnodcoms not [every time](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-unset-value)

Comment: OK you got me, nothing in webdesign 'Works every time'...

Comment: try using revert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `none` value only applies to `max-height` / `max-width`. This is because there is no limit on the height / width of the box. Hence, the default value for these properties is `none`.

The `none` value is not permitted on `min-height` / `min-width` because boxes cannot have negative height / width. Hence, the default value for these properties is `0`.

Spec references:

- [10.4 Minimum and maximum widths: `min-width` and `max-width`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#min-max-widths)
- [10.7 Minimum and maximum heights: `min-height` and `max-height`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#min-max-heights)

Comment: Note that the initial value of min-width and min-height is auto in css-flexbox-1, which is computed with its own set of rules for flex items, and computed to 0 for all other elements. This has not yet been acknowledged in css-box.

Comment: @BoltClock, yes, in a flex (and grid) layout those properties have different initial values than CSS 2.1/2. Thanks for highlighting that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually default value for min-height and min-width is `0`.

`auto` and `none` have not the same meaning:

For max-[prop],
`none` is: no limit on the height/width of the box, it grows as long as it can. It's not an automatic. It literally has no limit, none.

For min-[prop], `auto` is: "The default minimum size for flex items, providing a more reasonable default than 0 for other layouts".
What is: min(0, x), where x >= 0 and x is minimum size "acceptable element without having overflow". It is an **auto**matic adjust.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some logic behind this as the element *has* to have a minimal height even if this height is zero.

Conversely, the use of `none` in regard to `max-height` is logical, there are (in theory) an infinite amount of values that it can be as the element can use as much height as necessary.

In the words of the spec:

> **none**
>
> (Only on 'max-height') No limit on the height of the box.

[Minimum and maximum heights: 'min-height' and 'max-height'](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#min-max-heights)

There is no limit to the maximum height of the box it can be as big as it wants, but there is a limit to the minimum height of the box as it can only go down to  zero (negative height values are not valid).

In CSS 2.1 the initial value of `min-height` was `0`, the flexbox module introduced `auto` as the initial value. The reason why `auto` works is that it computes to `0` (if the flexbox model is not in use) effectively unsetting the value:

> **auto**
>
> On a flex item whose overflow is visible in the main axis, when
> specified on the flex item’s main-axis min-size property, specifies an
> automatic minimum size. **It otherwise computes to 0 (unless otherwise
> defined by a future specification).**

[Implied Minimum Size of Flex Items](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)